# Retornar valor AsyncStorage em uma constante

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, ecmascript-6

Estou tentando há algum tempo retorna um item armazenado no AsyncStorage do react native, porém o retorno é sempre uma **Promise**, porém o que desejo é tomar decisões com esse retorno posteriormente, e conseguir acessar o valor fora do escopo da Promise! o que desejo fazer é:

```
const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
```

Assim podendo utilizar a constante **user** posteriormente, isso é possível? 
Se não for possível é realmente necessário englobar todo o que desejo fazer dentro da promise? e qual a alternativa para isso?

**EDIT**

O objetivo de utilizar o AsyncStorage aqui é recuperar o usuário logado, desta forma consigo direcionar ele para home se estiver logado ou para o login se não estiver na inicialização do App. A ideia é alterar o **initialRouteName**. Algo parecido com isso:

```
let initialScreen = 'Login'
AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(user => {
  if(user) initialScreen = 'Home'
})

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',
      header: null
    },
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Login',
      header: null
    },
  }
}, {initialRouteName: initialScreen});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
export default AppContainer
```

Muito obrigado!

Comment: o retorno da consulta é uma string json ou apenas uma string simples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use uma função `async` e coloque `await` antes do AsyncStorage:

```
async function pegarValor(){
    const myuser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    console.log(myuser)
}


pegarValor();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const AppNavigator = AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(user => {
    if (user) {
        initialScreen = 'Home'
        this.user = user

        return createStackNavigator({
            Home: {
                screen: Home,
                navigationOptions: {
                    title: 'Home',
                    header: null
                },
            },
            Login: {
                screen: Login,
                navigationOptions: {
                    title: 'Login',
                    header: null
                },
            }
        }, { initialRouteName: 'Login' });
    }
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
export default AppContainer
```

Comment: Tentei desta forma e obtenho o seguinte erro: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'component.router.getStateForAction'), estou quase utilizando um modal para esse menu! haha

Comment: Mano, alterei o código, vê o que da agora

Comment: Infelizmente não rolou, obtenho o mesmo erro (evaluating 'component.router.getStateForAction')

Answer (score 0):

Não tem problema em fazer isso. Exemplo:

```
async function Test() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({"testando":123});
        }, 1000);
    });
}

const test = await Test();
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funciona desta forma, obtenho erro no await no build

Answer (score 0):

Ou você pode colocar no componentDidMount do componente:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
...
let user;
class sua_class extends Component {
  async componentDidMount {
    user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
  }
render(){...}
}
```

Comment: voce nao esta usando redux?

Comment: Se ele usar o Redux da certo tbm. De qualquer forma é uma promise então precisa aguardar a resposta.

Comment: Interessante, porém não consegui aplicar no meu caso... existe outra alternativa? LocalStorage por exemplo?

Comment: Você está usando o React Native mesmo certo? Lá é só com AsyncStorage. Ele é assíncrono ai usa o async/await. Posta ai como vc tá fazendo e qual erro tá dando pra ajudar melhor.

Comment: Editei acima, e adicionei o código que estou tentando implementar, no meu caso não é um component de classe pois não encontrei nenhuma forma de usar o **createAppContainer** com components de classe